# Firefox addons on seamonkey

Tags: firefox, seamonkey

Many addons for firefox don't work on seamonkey. Is there any risk in overriding the security settings? Or is there perhaps a tool that allows for compatibility?

I like the idea of a calendar and mailclient in the same piece of software, but if I can't use the addons I use in firefox, I'm sticking with firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked through the [Seamonkey addons list](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/seamonkey/)?
Here is also a [blog reference from PuppyLinux](http://www.puppylinux.com/blog/?viewDetailed=00547) (which uses Seamonkey).

> There are many addons for SeaMonkey, and many Firefox addons can also work in SeaMonkey. There is a site that has some Firefox addons modified for SeaMokey:
>
> > http://xsidebar.mozdev.org/modifiedmisc.html

<sub>Seamonkey is great if you are already using [PuppyLinux](http://www.puppylinux.com/).</sub>

Comment: [The xSidebar addon is no more required for Seamonkey 2.0+](http://xsidebar.mozdev.org/modifiedmisc.html)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to add this addon to seamonkey : [checkcompatibility](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/)

Most of the time, it won't work, but sometime, it can force seamonkey to install an addon supposed to be incompatible for no good reason.

Comment: I checked your link and that addon is only available for Firefox, so I would imagine that's the wrong way around!? :-)

Comment: Sorry, but you shall verify again here https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/versions/ : "working with Firefox 4.0 - 56.*, SeaMonkey 2.1 - 2.11a1, Thunderbird 3.3a1 - 31.* ". By the way, all of this is outdated.

Comment: Ah, I see the comment also, but the button does not let me download anything for SeaMonkey. It forces me to go download Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is [Seamonkey Compatibility Tables of Converted Extensions](http://addonconverter.fotokraina.com/compatibility/) that can convert and install many FF extensions.