# Relation between Firefox and SeaMonkey

Tags: firefox, seamonkey

1. I was wondering what are the
   relations between Firefox and
   SeaMonkey?
2. Is it true that an extension for
   Firefox is usually not for
   SeaMonkey? I hope to that a
   particular extension called
   TorButton for Firefox to be found
   for SeaMonkey. But I found none. Can
   I find an extension for SeaMonkey
   equivalent to TorButton?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SeaMonkey is the open-source continuation of the original Mozilla project; Mozilla stopped development when they changed their focus to Firefox and Thunderbird. Firefox and SeaMonkey thus have a common ancestor and are built on the same platform, but will not necessarily have the same extensions available.

As [this earlier question](https://superuser.com/q/47567/41594) points out, there are some add-ons that are available for both browsers. You can check the [full list of SeaMonkey add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/seamonkey/?browse=featured); [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/seamonkey/search/?q=TorButton&cat=all&x=0&y=0) claims to offer more than TorButton does, but you'll have to see for yourself. I haven't used TorButton and my installation of SeaMonkey is clean (no add-ons).

Comment: also [here](http://addonconverter.fotokraina.com/compatibility/) a  Firefox-Seamonkey addon-compatibility database and addon converter.